# crystal report hash function

Tags: hash, crystal-reports

Is there a hashing function in crystal report? I need to create a report that generate a hashed value. This value will be displayed as 2d barcode, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.

In the past, I've used a SQL Expression to directly reference the database-engine's hash function, passing one of the field's to it.